# Adding CKEditor first party packages

Tags: plugins, ckeditor5

The plugin documentation for craft ckeditor says that first party packages include a build file that I need to add the plugin. I'm not seeing a build directory in any of the ckeditor first party packages. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have struggled with this one too, we could really do with some more detailed instructions on how to setup first party packages in the plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GitHub repository for CKEditor plugins doesn't include the bundled package, just the source files. You can build the plugins yourself, or you can grab the build from npm.

If your project already includes npm, you can install the package like this (this is for the `highlight` plugin, replace with your desired plugin):

```
npm install @ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight
```

Then you can grab the `build` folder from the `node_modules` and copy it to your `AssetBundle`. If you don't want to install the plugin and just grab the `build` folder, you can instead download the module as a `tar` file:

```
npm pack @ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight
tar -xzf ckeditor-ckeditor5-highlight-41.2.0.tgz
```

The [`pack` command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-pack) will download the package and place it in the current directory as an archive, `tar -xzf` will extract it. Then you can copy the `build` folder from the extracted folder.

You can find more info on where to place the plugin folder in [my answer here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/40905/11705).